# Is there any "personalized magazine"-style application?

Tags: software-recommendation

I use [Zite](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/zite/id419752338?mt=8&ls=1) on my ipad to create a "magazine" that changes according to my answer on whether i liked a certain article or not. Is there something like that for ubuntu?

Comment: I Seriously doubt it

Comment: any web app then?

Comment: The closest i could think of is using a RSS client

Comment: I already use rss for quite a while now, the reason i want this kind of application is to help me find you sites worth adding to my google reader account

Comment: Stumbleupon? It's a toolbar which you can thumbs up sites and thumbs them down dependant on whether you like them or not, clicking stumble takes you to a new site from one of the categories you select when you create an account, it sounds like this might be what you're looking for, I say give it a try. Otherwise you could try google reader with your feeds and after a few weeks look in recommended items, generally it's pretty good at finding blogs I would be interested in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to my idea i found the "sparks" feature of Google+. It might not be a desktop application (yet - i think they said they have plans to make a desktop app) but it works just fine. Until a better idea is found, i'll consider this one an "answer"

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for Zite on Ubuntu myself. And have failed so far to find something.

However, there are some news aggregators outthere that have nice little web-functionality which can easlily be used with your browser. It's not quite the zite experience but similarily helpful

E.g. 
Tweeted Times: http://tweetedtimes.com/#!/cvhhh
or 
http://paper.li